# How to use non-contiguous cell ranges in SumProduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a document with checkboxes used to apply or remove circulation quantities from different products (relevant data in the linked image). A single row will contain multiple circulation quantities for different products, as well as a checkbox for each product. The checkboxes are linked to the cells they're in so TRUE or FALSE values show up. I would like to sum circulation quantities in a single row based on whether the checkbox is checked (i.e. whether the cell returns TRUE or FALSE).

My solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(O12,S12,W12),(Q12,U12,X12))
```

This returns a #VALUE! error, I'm assuming because of the non-contiguous cell ranges. Where's the issue in my syntax? I've seen some people get around this kind of issue with INDIRECT() but I don't even know where to start with that.

If it helps, I am already using VBA elsewhere in the project, so a VBA solution would be fine with me.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5pjn.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CHOOSE() like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--CHOOSE({1,2,3},O12,S12,W12),CHOOSE({1,2,3},Q12,U12,X12))
```

[image]

---

But this formula is shorter and does what you want:

```
=O12*Q12+S12*U12+W12*X12
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! I had never used the Choose function before.

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.